# Seed Multiple Specific Data on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, faker

I want to seed a database table by using **local**, **s3** and **rackspace** using database seeder on Laravel. However, if I use this three specific name with the `$faker->randomElement()` method it just populate the same name multiple time and that's what I don't need. If possible, I also want to set the different value for the different column using `s3` or `rackspace` storage name.

```
$factory->define(App\Storage::class, function (\Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'storage' => $faker->randomElement(['s3', 'local', 'rackspace']),
        's3-key' => null,
        's3-secret' => null,
        's3-region' => null,
        's3-bucket' => null,
        'rackspace-username' => null,
        'rackspace-key' => null,
        'rackspace-container' => null,
        'status' => 'active'
    ];
})
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: try this and see if you are having the same result:  $faker->randomElements(['s3', 'local', 'rackspace'],1)[0]

Comment: That did the trick. However, didn't understand how this works. Also, what would be the way when I want to set the `s3-key` or other parameter specifically for `s3` or `rackspace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the Faker/Provider/Baser.class, it is using this line of code inside the `randomElement` Function which is duplicating the same random element over and over for the same instance due to the fact it is using `static::` keyword

```
static::randomElements($array, 1);
```

I'll report about it, for the moment use this piece of code:

```
$faker->randomElements(['s3', 'local', 'rackspace'],1)[0]
```